# How to redirect some subdomain pages to another page htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect a few (not all) subdomain pages to another address in `.htaccess`:

How can I redirect the following:

```
spb.example.com/blog/
ekb.example.com/blog/
spb.example.com/projects/
ekb.example.com/projects/
```

to

```
example.com/blog/
example.com/projects/
```

I've tried:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^spb.example.com/blog/$
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://example.com/blog/? [R=301,L]
```

But it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^spb.mytestsite.com/blog/$
> RewriteRule ^.*$ https://mytestsite.com/blog/? [R=301,L]
> ```

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the URL-path only. It does not contain the requested hostname (which is present in the `HTTP_HOST` server variable).

For example:

```
# Redirect "spb.example.com/blog/" to "example.com/blog/"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^spb\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/$ https://example.com/blog/ [R=301,L]
```

However, you can do all 4 redirects in a single rule by using a more flexible regex and backreferences.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:spb|ekb)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(blog|projects)/$ https://example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

The `$1` backreference contains either `blog` or `projects` from the requested URL-path (captured in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*).

NB: Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

---

**UPDATE:**

> How can I redirect all blog articles from subdomains the same rules For example: from `spb.example.com/blog/my-blog-article-1/` `ekb.example.com/blog/my-blog-article-1/` to `example.com/blog/my-blog-article-1/`

You could do it like this by adding a second capturing group to the existing rule above:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:spb|ekb)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(blog|projects)/(.*) https://example.com/$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How can I redirect all blog articles from subdomains the same rules
For example:
from
spb.example.com/blog/my-blog-article-1/
ekb.example.com/blog/my-blog-article-1/
to
example.com/blog/my-blog-article-1/

Comment: I redirect blog and projects pages use next rule, maybe some one need it
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:spb|ekb)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(blog/(.*)|projects/(.*))/$ https://example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]`

Comment: @Ruslan I've updated my answer to allow for "all blog articles" as well. So `/blog/` and `/blog/blog-article/` are handled by a single rule. A minor issue with your solution is that you need 2 rules, one for `/blog/` (as I initially posted) and one for `/blog/blog-article/` (the rule you've posted above). Note that this also allows `/ptojects/<anything>` as well to be redirected.

Comment: @Ruslan If this answered your question then please consider marking it as "accepted" (to help other readers and remove the question from the unanswered question queue). Thanks, much appreciated. :)