# Redirect robots.txt from http to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect my **robots.txt** from **http** to **https** in .htaccess

```
http://ekb.example.com/robots.txt to https://ekb.example.com/robots.txt
http://spb.example.com/robots.txt to https://ekb.example.com/robots.txt
```

I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ekb\.example\.com 
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ https://example.com/robots.txt [R=301,L]
```

But it isn't working.

Comment: First of all, that's a different domain you tried to redirect to.

Comment: "it isn't working" - What happens exactly? The rule you've posted redirects the `ekb` subdomain to the domain apex, but in your example you want to redirect `ekb` or `spb` subdomains to the `ekb` subdomain? Where is your `.htaccess` file? What other directives do you have in your `.htaccess` file(s)?

Comment: Second (assuming the domain is actually supposed to stay the same, and not go somewhere external), you need to check whether the current request was not made via HTTPS already - otherwise, you are creating an endless redirect loop there.

Comment: How did you get on with your previous (related) question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69480102/how-to-redirect-some-subdomain-pages-to-another-page-htaccess

Comment: I need to set 301 redirect from http: //spb.example.com/robots.txt на https:// spb.example.com/robots.txt c http:// ekb.example.com/robots.txt на https:// ekb.example.com/robots.txt

Answer (score 1):

> I need to set 301 redirect from `http://spb.example.com/robots.txt` to `https://spb.example.com/robots.txt` and `http://ekb.example.com/robots.txt` to `https://ekb.example.com/robots.txt`.

Ok, so you are wanting to redirect to the same host. However, this does raise a couple of questions as to why you want to do this?

1. If you have a site-wide HTTP to HTTPS redirect (as you probably should have) then requests for `robots.txt` would already be redirected (unless you have implemented an exception).
2. Whilst [Google does follow redirects for `robots.txt`](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt), other bots might not, so may just treat it like a 404 (ie. no `robots.txt` file - unrestricted crawl access).

   Ordinarily, there's no need to redirect `robots.txt`. Certainly, you shouldn't implement a specific redirect just for `robots.txt` when a site-wide HTTP to HTTPS redirect has not been implemented (see #1). After all, a `robots.txt` file located at HTTPS does not strictly apply to HTTP.

---

However, to implement the redirect you are asking, you would need to do something like the following at the top of your root `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "robots.txt" from HTTP to HTTPS for the two subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(ekb|spb)\.example\.com 
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$0 [R=301,L]
```

The `$0` backreference simply saves repetition and contains `robots.txt` from the matched URL-path.

This does assume the SSL cert is installed on the application and not controlled by an SLL proxy. (Otherwise, checking against `HTTPS` will likely result in a redirect loop.